# How to show and hide text by a button

Tags: text, button, graphics, gui-construction

I'm trying to implement a button that can show and hide output text in a panel/tab, but I can't find a specific command to do that. I tried StringReplace, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

```
showhide = Transpose@{#, ToExpression@#}&@{"Red", "Transparent"};
i = 1;
f = Mod[#, 2] &;
st = Blue;


Panel[Column@{Row@{Slider[Dynamic@x], Dynamic@Style[x, st]},
              Button["Set to " Dynamic@ToString@showhide[[1 + f@i, 1]], 
                     st = showhide[[1 + f[i++], 2]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

I really think that you should give more details about what you are looking for. As it is I had do a fair amount of guessing. Nevertheless, here is a demonstration that might give you ideas of how something like you are considering can be done

```
SeedRandom[111];
With[{
  words = "grumpy wizards make a toxic brew for the jovial queen" // StringSplit},
  With[{n = Length @ words},
    DynamicModule[{redness, reds, r = 1, blueness, blues, b = 1}, 
      reds = MapThread[{redness, Text[#1, #2]} &, {words, RandomReal[1., {n, 2}]}];
      blues = MapThread[{blueness, Text[#1, #2]} &, {words, RandomReal[1., {n, 2}]}];
      Dynamic @ Column[{
        Graphics[{reds, blues},
          Frame -> True,
          ImageSize -> Medium],
        Row[{
          Button[{"Show Red", "Hide Red"}[[Mod[r, 2] + 1]], 
            redness = {Red, Transparent}[[Mod[r++, 2] + 1]]],
          "  ",
          Button[{"Show Blue", "Hide Blue"}[[Mod[b, 2] + 1]], 
            blueness = {Blue, Transparent}[[Mod[b++, 2] + 1]]]}]},
      Alignment -> Right],
      Initialization :> (redness = Red; blueness = Blue;)]]]
```

This code could be made considerably more compact, but doing so would probably would make it less clear as a tutorial.

Initial display:

[image: both]

Hide Blue button clicked on:

[image: red]